# File not found exception using Yodlee API on android

Tags: yodlee

I am trying yodlee api on android but getting file not found exception when I called HTTP GET request on :  Request URL=https://developer.api.yodlee.com/ysl/restserver/v1/providers?name=icici.
When I used java sample api as standalone java application it's work fine but in android it is giving exception. cobrand as well member login works fine on android.

Answer (score 0):

You should first check the code, as this is not something which Yodlee API returns. Seems to be an issue with your android code. Do you mind updating the question with your code and actual exception you are getting?